# coordinate system transformation

Tags: coordinate-systems, classical-mechanics

I am trying to define a radial deformation (same deformation radially) regarding Cartesian coordinates. The problem is that the cylinder is curved, i.e., the center of the cylinder doesn't follow the axis, i.e.:
[image: curved pipe]

I know how to do the coordinate transformation for the straight section, just not sure how to do it for the curved section. The center of the pipe in this region can be defined as:
$$y = \sqrt{(0.03)^2 - (x-0.03)^2} + 0.15, y > 0.15$$

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to translate each "slice" of the curved part of the cylinder to be inline with the axis, perform the deformation and then translate it back?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the blending of a cylinder and a torus as shown in the attached graphics.

[image]

The torus parametric equation is

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x & = & (a\cos (u)+c) \cos (v) \\
y & = & (a\cos (u)+c) \sin (v) \\
z & = & a\sin (u) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

such that

$$
c = \;\;\mbox{torus main radius}\\
a = \;\;\mbox{tube radius}
$$